# Can I make a maven library repository that can be available by all selenium projects?

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, webdriver

Can I make a default maven library repository that can be used automatically when making a new maven project? If yes, how? Tried searching this matter in google but I can't find what I am looking for.

Here is what I want to accomplished.
1. Make a Maven Library repository which contains all the dependencies that I need. (i.e selenium java, TestNG and Apache poi)
2. Use this maven repository by default whenever I create a new Maven Project in Eclipse

Comment: What do you want? Your own maven repository _server_ like artifactory? Or do you want a local repository like `~/.m2/repository`, which you could create from scratch and zip it?

Comment: I want to make a maven repository wherein I can put default dependencies. So that whenever I create a new maven project this dependencies would be present by default. I have 1 Default dependency whenever I create a new maven project and that is JUnit.

Comment: Why is this tagged with selenium and webdriver? No relation to the question, AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can create a separate maven project like tests-parent-pom only with pom.xml file which contains all the dependencies that you need. For each new Maven project you can add tests-parent-pom project like a parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>tests-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Then all dependencies will be added to new project